# Having issues with running notification in my application android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

Hello guys i would like to ask about a problem i'm facing with notification in android 11 , i have set up the whole code but when i run it in android oreo it works pretty , not sure if it is because of system itself or my code

- This is my code

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.channelId)).apply {
                setContentTitle(data.dateEvent.plus(" / ").plus(data.strTime))
                setContentText(data.strEvent)
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_active_24)
                setContentIntent(taskBuilder)
                setChannelId(context.getString(R.string.channelId))
                setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH
                setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                                     
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
                 .notify(counter++, build())
             }
```

Comment: I don't get your problem when the code runs pretty

Comment: the code runs well versions below oreo and oreo , but for example when i test witt his code on device with android 11 , the notification is not triggered , don't know if it is because of the system or the code itself ( tried on oneplus and xiami devices with android 11 ) in both devices the notification is not triggered

Comment: Did you make sure to create a channel before issueing the notification? There are changes at API 26.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications .
You should also make sure that you enabled notifications for the app and the channel of the notification is also enabled.

Comment: yes i'm aware of the changes after android oreo that we should create notification with channel id , as i said it works fine on oreo , but since i'm using the same , on android 11 is not working , notifcations options is enabled , i'm just confused why is it not working..